# Ensuring an inline item always appears last

Tags: html, css

I'm implenting an HTML Message dialog.

[image]

The recipient entry panel is shown above - a number of recipients, and a text box at the end (which will be invisible) for adding new recipients by means of an autocomplete menu.

I've implemented it at the moment as an unordered list displayed inline:

```
<ul class="recipients inline clearfix">
    <li class="recipient"><span>recipient 1<a href="#" class="remove">x</a></span></li>
    <li class="recipient"><span>recipient 2<a  href="#" class="remove">x</a></span></li>
    <li class="recipient last"><span>recipient 3<a  href="#" class="remove">x</a></span></li>
    <li class="searchbox"><input type="text" class="search-recipient"></li>
</ul>

ul.inline li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

The  problem is when the recipients go onto multiple lines, the textbox moves up to fill available space:

[image]

How do I make the textbox always appear after the recipients?

Comment: This should not happen given the code we have here. There must be something else going on, like your list items or the spans or the textbox being floated for example.

Answer (score 0):

The code your provided should work as intended. You are probably having some sort of float set on the input box.

See **[Live Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/2712246)**